# Deploying Streamlit App on Railways. Fixing deploying error?

Tags: python, deployment, streamlit, railway

I am deploying a basic streamlit app on railway. It builds perfects but runs into error while deploying.

The error:

Error: No such option: --client.toolbarMode
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

I tried reading streamlit and railway docs but couldn't find anything related

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.